# display background color for particular time in textview android

Tags: android, textview

In my application I am using gcm to update data. first the data are saved in database and then displays in textviews.What I need is, when data is updated, I have to change the background color of textview just for 2 seconds.Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html If you want smooth changes to the colour.

Answer (score 1):

U can use a Handler :

```
final View v = findViewById(R.id.yourView);

// Change the color
v.setBackgroundColor(color1);
Handler h = new Handler ; 
h.postAtTime(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run() {
            // Change color after 2 seconds
            v.setBackgroundColor(color2);                                           
        }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a Runnable class

```
private Runnable revertTextViewColor = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);  //Put your original color here

    }
};
```

Then when database is updated and textview needs to be highlighted
Change the color of textview

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); //Put any color here
Handler customHandler = new Handler();   //Create a handler
customHandler.postDelayed(revertTextViewColor , 2000);  //Schedule the color to revert to original color in 2 secs i.e. 2000ms
```